# Can I stipulate that EC2 instances in a certain launch config use my Reserved Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have an ASG with a Launch Config that uses the instance type I've purchased Reserved Instances for, but I want to ensure that this ASG/Launch Config gets first dibs on the purchased Reserved Instances for **ensuring Capacity only**.

It's possible that other applications/users/roles will launch the same EC2 instance type, but I want to ensure that my ASG/Launch Config gets the capacity assurances that come with purchasing Reserved instances.

For the cost savings, I understand the RIs apply to all accounts under a payor account, but I'm concerned specifically with ensuring capacity.

Is there a way to set Capacity priority to a specific Autoscaling Group/Launch config?

Comment: I think you can disable sharing of RIs in AWS Orgs. So then only your account can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this is available for capacity reservations.

If you need to ensure that only a specific ASG would be able to use them, you'd need to have the RIs purchased in that account and have RI sharing across accounts disabled, and not run any other instances that match the RI in the associated AZs.